# Removing a textfield from JFrame dynamically

Tags: java, spring, jframe

I want to remove the text field upon selecting the radio button "don't show field" but unable to do so. I have used repaint and revalidate methods. I also tried making the field invisible by setting visibility to false but nothing seems to be working.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
}
}

class Frame 
{
private JFrame frame;
private JButton button;
private ImageIcon img;
private JRadioButton b1;
private JRadioButton b2;
private JTextField text;
public Frame()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    text=new JTextField(10);
    b1=new JRadioButton("show Field");
    b2=new JRadioButton("Dont show field");
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(b1);
    bg.add(b2);
    img = new ImageIcon("Letter-S-icon.png");

    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {
                    if(arg.getSource()==b1)
                    {
                        frame.add(text);
                        frame.revalidate();
                        frame.repaint();
                    }
                    else if(arg.getSource()==b2)
                    {
                        text.setVisible(false);
                        frame.remove(text);//cannot remove this even after repaint(); 
                        frame.revalidate();
                        frame.repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.add(b2);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBounds(500, 200, 200, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());

 }
 }
```

Comment: You only listen to the actions of `b1`. Nothing ever happens if you select `b2`

Comment: but this could still work if you add an ItemListener to the b1 radiobutton

Comment: thanks a lot @XtremeBaumer it worked.